# Query execution is taking too long

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, mysql-workbench, database-administration

I currently have two tables in a database. Called Email and unsuscribed both tables have a column called Email. now I want to compare these two tables and wherever email matches I want to update column in email table called Email_status_id to 2...the query I am using is

```
UPDATE  Email E
SET E.Email_status_id = 2
WHERE 
    E.Email
  IN (
    SELECT 
     U.Email
    FROM 
     UNSUSCRIBED U);
```

I am currently using mysql.

email table has 2704569 rows of Email
and unsuscribed table has 12102 rows of Email

the query execution time is taking forever....

any suggestion to reduce query execution time...

Comment: [DBA](http://dba.stackexchange.com) might be a better place for this, but in any case, no assessment could be done w/o showing the table schema.

Comment: Do you have an index on the `Email.Email` column?

Comment: Need more info. Indexes?  Also, I don't think this is a DBA question.  It's just a query/index tune. If you don't have indexes on the `Email` field on both of these tables, that would be a GREAT place to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing is to create an index on `Unsubscribed(Email)`:

```
create index idx_unsubscribed_email on unsubscribed(email);
```

Or, even better, declare it as the `primary key`, particularly if it is the only column in the table.

Then, MySQL sometimes does a poor job of implementing `in`.  There are a variety of ways to write the query making use of the index.  `Exists` is a typical method:

```
update email e
     set email_status_id = 2
     where exists (select 1 from unsubscribed u where u.email = e.email);
```

The `join` version should have similar performance with the index.

EDIT:

An index on `email(email)` could also help the query.  For some reason, I assumed that this would already be a key in the table.

Comment: thanks you very much ,,that worked...Query Execution time is greatly reduced

Answer (score 1):

You're doing string comparisons over a large amount of data in an `In` clause.  Since you don't actually need the data returned, you can do this in an `Exists`:

```
Update  Email E
Set     E.Email_status_id = 2
Where Exists
(
    Select  1
    From    Unsubscribed    U
    Where   U.Email = E.Email
)
```

Aside from that, proper [indexing](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html) on the `Email` column in both the `Email` and `Unsubscribed` tables would up your performance as well.

Answer (score 0):

IN statements against entire tables are usually slow.  This is because it has to run your subquery against every single line in the table to get your filtered result set.  Try using a join instead, like so:

```
Update Unsubscribed U join Email E on E.Email=U.Email
SET E.email_status_id = 2
```